# Using CURL with discord.js and 5sim API

Tags: api, curl, discord, discord.js, bots

Im trying to make a command for my discord bot, so I can get a verification code for any kind of account from 5sim via their api... I think im very close since some of my code worked in https://reqbin.com/req/c-vdhoummp/curl-get-json-example... but im having trouble implementing it into my command! This is my first time using Curl so im not too familiar, but I was wondering if anyone could give me some help with my broken code?

```
const Discord = require(`discord.js`)
const curl = require(`curl`)

module.exports = {
    name: `buynumber`,
    description: `buys a phone number!`,
    async execute(message) {
      const response = curl 'https://5sim.net/v1/user/buy/activation/cambodia/any/yahoo',
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer MYAUTHORIZATIONTOKENHERE",
            Accept: "application/json"
          }
         }; data = await response.json()


            message.channel.send(data.number)
    }}
```

the current error im facing is

```
[Sun Sep 12 2021 21:26:16] [LOG]   Initializing Startup!
[Sun Sep 12 2021 21:26:16] [ERROR] (node:12692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\Users\manof\Desktop\Main Bots\Celly Bot\commands\buy.js:8
      const response = curl "https://5sim.net/v1/user/buy/activation/cambodia/any/discord",
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

can you try doing

```js
const response = curl('https://5sim.net/v1/user/buy/activation/cambodia/any/yahoo', {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer MYAUTHORIZATIONTOKENHERE",
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
});
const data = await response.json();
```

Because your syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the function `curl.get` in the curl package and hence it requires you to call it via `()` this is a simple syntax error and can be fixed like so:

```js
let data;
      const response = curl.get('https://5sim.net/v1/user/buy/activation/cambodia/any/yahoo',
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer MYAUTHORIZATIONTOKENHERE",
            Accept: "application/json"
          }
         });
data = await response.json()
```

I suggest you to read the examples given [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/curl)